# What is 'remotes/remotename/HEAD' in my cloned Git repo?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-clone, git-remote

I'm trying to set up a local Git repository that uses a specific branch from another repository as a starting template (possibly pulling changes to the template, but never — or at least almost never — pushing to the template) and I'm puzzled by the difference between two approaches:

If I

```
git clone --origin framework --branch template <repo_url> <repo_directory> --single-branch
cd <repo_directory>
git remote set-url --push framework DISABLED
```

I have a `remotes/framework/HEAD` remote branch, while if I instead

```
mkdir <repo_directory>
cd <repo_directory>
git init
git remote add framework <repo_url>
git pull framework template:template
```

everything else is (or at least seems) the same, except for the absence of `remotes/framework/HEAD`.

What is `remotes/framework/HEAD` and why is it present in one approach and not another?

---

I gather the only way to prevent pushing to the remote repo in either case is with something like

```
git remote set-url --push framework DISABLED
```

but if there is another approach (other than the two above) to configuring a local repo that meets my goals, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a marker for the default branch of your remote. For example in GitHub it is the branch you see when you open the project, and you can change it in the settings dialog.

I think you get it only when you pull all branches (and when it exists). In your second example you only pull a single branch.

The remote head can be specified with `-m` when you `git remote add` a remote, and you can use `git remote set-head` to modify it.

BTW: if you pull from a URL without setting up a remote, then you dont need to worry about making it un-push-able.

BTW2: with the latest git you can also use `--reference repository --dissociate` when you do a clone poiting to a local version. This avoids the need to download all the files (but still copies them so you dont need to worry if you want to delete the source).

Comment: But in the first example I was (or thought I was) pulling only a single branch too (with `--single-branch`).

Comment: Also: I'd like to make the remote branch pullable though, so that I can (for example) look in on the evolution of the template and possibly incorporate changes from it into the local project I started from it.